# How to bind USB device under a static name?

Tags: android, android-fragments, touch, embedded-linux, udev

I have an USB device which sometimes gets bound to /dev/input/event0 and other times to /dev/input/event1 etc. making my script fail.

I do not want to enumerate all the possibilities of where my device could be, but I rather have it be bound somewhere static, e.g. /dev/input/eventx.

I have seen that we could use udev rules to achieve this in Linux (ubuntu).

**How do I do that in Android?Please Help.**

Note: I am using Android in a Raspberry pi development board.

Comment: Is there any mechanism like udev in android? Or should we do it in the application itself?

Comment: In Linux there is "evtest" console program to list all the devices with its names. Maybe it is also available in Android?